# Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; near ')' at line 1

Tags: php, mysql, server

Im having a problem with my PHP code, it says the error is "Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1"

It connects to the database ok as it echos "Database Connection Successful" but it dosnt insert the data into the database. This worked fine before, but now all of a sudden its stopped working. Can anyone help?

```
<?php   
$username = "student";
$password = "student";
$hostname = "localhost"; 
$db       = "details";
$link = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $db);

 if ($link->connect_errno)
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $link->connect_error);
 else 
    echo "Database Connection Successful \n";

 echo nl2br("\n");

 $Urgency = "Urgency";

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $TypeOfProblem = $_POST['problemtype'];
  $ProblemDescription = $_POST['problem'];
  $RoomNo = $_POST['roomno'];
  $Problem = $_POST['reporter'];
  $Urgency = $_POST['Urgency'];
  $Date = $_POST['date'];

 //Insert into Database
  $sql = "INSERT INTO `details`.`problem` (`Type Of Problem`, `Problem Description`, `RoomNo`, `Urgency`, `UserIDProblem`,`Date` ) VALUES ('$TypeOfProblem', '$ProblemDescription', '$RoomNo', '$Urgency', '$Problem', $Date)";

if (!mysqli_query($link, $sql))
       {
       die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($link));
       }

     echo "\n Thank you. Your Helpdesk Call has been submitted.";

    mysqli_close($link);

}//////// end isset submit if ////////
 ?>
```

Thanks

Comment: Your date needs to be inside quotes. Also, sql injection warning. Learn to bind your queries. It is easy and helps.

Comment: Could it be because $Date is not enclosed in ' ' ?

Comment: Try to set an echo after the $sql =      echo $sql;   I think also that the problem is the single quote `details`.`problem` (` should be   'details'.'problem' ('

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), and you should show us what `$sql` looks like. Most likely `$Date` is empty, leaving you with `...,'foo',)`, which is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this, the problem is the single quote ` should be '

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO 'details'.'problem' ('Type Of Problem', 'Problem Description', 'RoomNo', 'Urgency', 'UserIDProblem','Date' ) VALUES ('$TypeOfProblem', '$ProblemDescription', '$RoomNo', '$Urgency', '$Problem', '$Date')"
```

Or try to set an `echo $sql` and test the query  directly on de dbms

Answer (score 0):

The date `'$Problem', $Date)";` needs single-quotes `'$Problem', '$Date')";`

Answer (score 0):

For debugging this, output the actual SQL text that is being submitted to the database, using `echo` or `vardump` e.g.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO ...";
echo "SQL=" . $sql ;
```

That will show you the actual statement that's going to be submitted to the database, and you can usually debug the problem from there.

If `date` isn't a numeric, if it represents a `DATE` datatype or a string, the value needs to be enclosed in single quotes. Otherwise, it's likely going to be interpreted in a numeric context.

---

Note that this code appears to be vulnerable to **SQL Injection**, because it includes potentially unsafe values in the SQL text. Consider what happens when a value contains "special" characters, like a single quote, or comma.

Potentially unsafe values *must* be properly escaped. With mysqli, you can use the `mysqli_real_escape_string` function.

A better pattern is to use a **prepared statement** with **bind placeholders**.

---

As an example of what that would look like (before it's cluttered up with code to checks for errors from the return of the mysqli_ function calls)

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `details`.`problem`
       (`Type Of Problem`,`Problem Description`,`RoomNo`,`Urgency`,`UserIDProblem`,`Date`)
       VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";

$sth = mysqli_prepare($link,$sql);
if (!$sth) {
   echo "error:" . mysqli_error($link);
)

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($sth,"ssssss"
    ,$TypeOfProblem,$ProblemDescription,$RoomNo,$Urgency,$Problem,$Date); 

mysqli_stmt_execute($sth);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, it is a good idea to leave out the database name:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `problem` (`Type Of Problem`, `Problem Description`, `RoomNo`, `Urgency`, `UserIDProblem`, `Date`) VALUES ('$TypeOfProblem', '$ProblemDescription', '$RoomNo', '$Urgency', '$Problem', $Date)";
```

Are you  sure, that your column names have spaces in it? I mean this would work, but this is not a good idea, I think.

I cannot find another problem in your query, maybe you should quote the date:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `problem` (`Type Of Problem`, `Problem Description`, `RoomNo`, `Urgency`, `UserIDProblem`, `Date`) VALUES ('$TypeOfProblem', '$ProblemDescription', '$RoomNo', '$Urgency', '$Problem', '$Date')";
```

Otherwise, please provide us with the full query:

```
die("INSERT INTO `problem` (`Type Of Problem`, `Problem Description`, `RoomNo`, `Urgency`, `UserIDProblem`, `Date`) VALUES ('$TypeOfProblem', '$ProblemDescription', '$RoomNo', '$Urgency', '$Problem', $Date)");
```

And you SHOULD notice, that your code is exploitable with SQL-Injections! Use `mysqli_real_escape_string`.

Comment: Leaving out the database name is not a good idea. Why in the world would that be a good idea?

Comment: @JayBlanchard: The database name is already specified with the MySQLi connect.

Comment: True, but that doesn't mean you have to leave it out, right?

Comment: @JayBlanchard: You do not have to, but why should you? Should it be necessary to change hundreds of positions instead of one, if you change the database name?